# Rails, an almost working method to detect blacklisted hostname in email

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex, arrays, detect

I wrote method to detect if the hostname inside :email exists in an array of blacklisted hostname's to no avail I have the method almost working but can't figure it out:

```
host = email.split("@").last // e.g. "hotmail.com"
bad_hostnames = %w(rtrtr.com )

if /.*(#{bad_hostnames.join("|")}).*\@/.match(host)
  errors.add(:email, "Invalid temp mail provider")
end
```

What am I missing here? The regex is hard to test. Seems that the dot is causing issues, a similar method to check for certain blacklisted words in emails is working fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are looking for this code:

```
if /^(#{bad_hostnames.join("|")})$/.match(host)
```

or this one:

```
if /\@(#{bad_hostnames.join("|")})$/.match(email)
```